# Significant difference in speed between fsck using ext3 and ext4 on Debian Squeeze

Tags: debian, ext4, ext3, fsck

Recently I installed Debian Squeeze, first using `ext3` and then again using `ext4` on the same machine. The automatic `fsck` done after a certain number of mounts is much faster using `ext4` (about 1 min) than `ext3` (about 5 min).

What are the reasons for this significant difference in speed? If `ext4` is much faster why does the Debian installer default to using `ext3`?

Comment: The last part of your question should be addressed to the Debian dev team, really.

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz: there may be someone here who has a link to a public discussion that resulted in the decision.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's one of the most advertised benefits of *ext4* (see it mentioned in the [*Features*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4#Features) on Wikipedia).

The reason? *Filesystem developers worked hard to achieve this.*

Here's a short summary quoted from Wikipedia:

> **Faster file system checking**
>
> In ext4, unallocated block groups and sections of the inode table are marked as such. This enables e2fsck to skip them entirely on a check and greatly reduces the time it takes to check a file system of the size ext4 is built to support.